# Skip 2 Index In the body of For Loop VS While Loop ( Python VS C++)

Tags: python, c++

In the first code below (Using for loop) When I want to skip 2 index by increasing the index within the body of for loop, it ignores `i = i+2` and updates the index only with `for i in range (len(c))` phrase, while in the c++ we could do this in th e body of for loop by `for (int i = 0 ; i <sizeof(c) ;i++){i += 2;}`. Is there anyway to implement this using a for loop (by correcting first code) or I have to use a while loop (second code)?

**First Code (For loop)**

```
def jumpingOnClouds(c):

    count_jumps = 0 
    
    for i in range (len(c)):       

        if (i+2 <len(c) and c[i] == 0 and c[i+2] ==0):
            i = i+2
            count_jumps+=1#It doesnt let me to update i in the while loop
            
        elif (i+1 <len(c) and c[i] == 0 and c[i+1] ==0):
            
            count_jumps+=1
        
        else:
            pass    
        
    return(count_jumps)
  
c = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
   
jumpingOnClouds(c)
```

**Second Code (While Loop)**

```
def jumpingOnClouds(c):

    count_jumps = 0 
    
    i = 0
    
    while( i < len(c)):       

        if (i+2 <len(c) and c[i] == 0 and c[i+2] ==0):
            i = i+2
            count_jumps+=1
            
        elif (i+1 <len(c) and c[i] == 0 and c[i+1] ==0):
            
            count_jumps+=1
            i = i+1
        
        else:
            i = i+1   
        
    return(count_jumps)
c = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
   
jumpingOnClouds(c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `continue` to skip. You'll just need a condition that will be `True`.

```
def jumpingOnClouds(c):
    skipCondition = False
    count_jumps = 0 
    
    for i in range (len(c)):       
        if skipCondition:
            skipCondition = False
            continue
        if (i+2 <len(c) and c[i] == 0 and c[i+2] ==0):
            count_jumps+=1#It doesnt let me to update i in the while loop
            skipCondition = True
            continue
            
        elif (i+1 <len(c) and c[i] == 0 and c[i+1] ==0):
            
            count_jumps+=1
        
        else:
            pass    
        
    return(count_jumps)
  
c = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
   
jumpingOnClouds(c)
```

Putting `continue` will continue iterating, but before that, it will make the `skipCondition = True`. The next iteration, `skipCondition` will be `True`, so you will skip again, but setting `skipCondition` back to `False`

Comment: Using Python for such a case seems much easier to use while loop, right?

Comment: Yes, it would be easier, but if you specifically want to use `for`, this is an option to do so